# Nested for loop exits to the parent loop before it completes

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a nested for loop in VBA where I loop through all rows in a range and then within that I loop through all cells in the row.  I want to add up the number of green cells in a row.

```
For Each r In rngData.Cells
    For Each c In r.Columns
        If c.Interior.Color = cGreen Then
            dur = dur + 1
        End If
    Next c
dur = 0
Next r
```

The trouble is that after `next c` the code jumps down to `next r` so dur keeps getting reset to 0 where I want it to add up the number of green cells.

I would expect the code to complete the c loop before going to the next r loop.  What am I not seeing?

Comment: Your r loop is processing *cells*, not *rows*. A cell only has one column. Given that you don't do anything with `dur` this seems a bit pointless currently.

Comment: My gosh you're right I'm a fool.  It should be For Each r In rngData.rows

Comment: @Rory if you post the answer I'll close the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
For Each r In rngData.Rows
    For Each c In r.Cells
        If c.Interior.Color = cGreen Then
            dur = dur + 1
        End If
    Next c
dur = 0
Next r
```